# Create Dictionary For Mobile Using J2ME

Tags: java-me

I want to create the dictionary for mobile. But I have any idea about it. Could anybody guide to learn about these?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to elaborate a bit. What kind of a dictionary?

If what you want a list of word pairs, for example to translate between two languages such as English and German, and it is a fairly short list, you could use an in-memory hash table. There is a class **Hashtable** for this in CLDC. If you need a larger dictionary, you might want to store it on a memory card, and then it gets a bit more complicated to search it. There are also relational databases (such as Mimer SQL Mobile) that can be run under J2ME, and you might look at that option for storage and search.

EDIT:

The original poster added a question as a comment to this answer, about putting a list in a form. [This page](http://basen.oru.se/kurser/j2me/2009-2010-p12/lektioner/lektion-06/index.html) gives some code examples that might serve as an introduction, although the explanations are in Swedish.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I know what you said. could you give me reference ebooks or other that can do this?

Comment: and I don't how to design the list and textbox for searching

Comment: Sopolin: You can start at http://java.sun.com/javame and follow some of the links from there.

Comment: Hi Thomas,I know the code. But I don't how to design text and list word in one form. My mention is I have one mobile (sony ericsson K530i) and I want to design one form that have text box and list of word. In J2ME , it has a list but it can't put in one form. I don't know to create it. Help me!... Thanks Sopolin

Answer (score -1):

[DictionaryForMIDs](http://dictionarymid.sourceforge.net/) is a project which does specifically this, and its open source so you can do necessary changes. I think they already have a java mobile application with a simple textbox. It uses a stripdown version of Wordnet 2.0 dictionary, Wordnet is an excellent lexical database of English.

Although, DictionaryForMIDs does the job, it has some bugs which are fairly noticeable.
See if you can make something out of it.

Comment: Hi detj, I am using NetBeans 6.7.1. I don't know to design the graphic that have text and list in one form of java2me. I see they can add both in one graphic. So how can I do? Thanks